# .live is not a function

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a main gridview this one has a column where I can contract and expand for to show the second gridview.
But when I try to expand the row in the console side show this message 
.live is not a function. I have been reading some articules about it but just one help me a lot of.

Answer (score 0):

*.- Use jquery-1.9.1.min.js and paste the follow code
* jQuery.fn.extend({live: function (event, callback) {if (this.selector) {jQuery(document).on(event, this.selector, callback);}}});